# How to add unique header to react application?

Tags: reactjs, cloudflare

I have a react Application that's hosted on a S3 bucket with CloudFlare CDN on the front. Now as a part of the deploy pipeline, we run a bunch of End-to-End tests that runs against a given environment (say [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)). However on CloudFlare we have rules setup so that if an IP tried to invoke the application repeatedly then we present a Captcha to avoid DDOS attack. What is happening is when the deploy server is running the E2E tests, CloudFlare starts blocking the requests and then the tests start to fail. I checked with the DevOps team if they can Whitelist the build server IP but they said they can't. Instead they want me to add a unique header that they can check in CloudFlare and then exclude.

So my question is how can I add a request header to my react App? I mean I know how to add to any request the app is making but when a browser is making a request to my App, how do I add the unique header there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```js
fetch('/example.json', {
    headers: new Headers({
        'Accept': 'text/plain',
        'X-Your-Custom-Header': 'example value'
    })
});
```